# download direct file

Tags: c#, download

I want to download a file directly from a url (for example: `http://iranfairco.com/icon/Iranfairco.png`)
and save this file on our server.

How do I do this?

Comment: Via a script? program? browser? Browser is easy - hit the url, then do file->save as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `WebClient.DownloadFile(url,local)` e.g.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://iranfairco.com/icon/Iranfairco.png",@"c:\mypng.png");
```

Comment: Just as I've shown above.  You specify the local file url as the second argument.